# How to delete the different extensions for many files?

Tags: rename, multiple-columns

Now I have many files, but with messy names. For example:

```
pre_day_19861106.txt0911_Vw7%2FzJSe5KwHIE9EOxbaJaO1e6c%3D
pre_day_20101222.txt1501_zOPHyWs3aIC7Z54yHL0ts%2BiX9bo%3D
pre_day_19861107.txt0911_EdGtVc1aaXGAs747hzPCVCt7wU0%3D
pre_day_20101223.txt1501_bbCw6m7LvaUbZ5bGzAFNev0%2BGhw%3D
pre_day_19861108.txt0911_kM9nUGCfMTUoRXhir2AwOQ7QQtw%3D
pre_day_20101224.txt1501_Pu9u4pxwz8vT6py6G9ts6Lh%2B1yc%3D
pre_day_19861109.txt0911_PNhwc8hmNWCjQ9HpQIkIAIrTy5c%3D
pre_day_20101225.txt1501_ckB9uZy2BeMbF8St6ZGC3cURaIc%3D
pre_day_19861110.txt0911_TnnM2XtOI6cs370EAl1RRM4XGx0%3D
pre_day_20101226.txt1501_DqJNIrTjs6HUVcYpPCUAWdKVf0o%3D
pre_day_19861111.txt0911_qIN7qS2%2F4wgs3TQh4kJZsdYVQTs%3D
pre_day_20101227.txt1502_0PDIuHiRxRyyfBSDYJAAP8hYdrE%3D
pre_day_19861112.txt0912_DXdVQU4ejGj8%2BTvKtvIUU6uzucw%3D
pre_day_20101228.txt1502_rONlbztFSPCNNxwLeNQ0tDTwQEA%3D
```

I don't know why strange name suffix attach after the "txt". So how to delete them and just keep the "txt".

Comment: Are you running under Windows?

Comment: Which shell version are you using? `bash`? How do you like the file names to be?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` with `awk` like this;

```
 find . -iname "*.txt*" | awk -F'.txt' '{ system("mv " $0 " " $1 ".txt") }'
```

This will rename `pre_day_19861106.txt0911_Vw7%2FzJSe5KwHIE9EOxbaJaO1e6c%3D` to `pre_day_19861106.txt`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It made.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows DOS you can just execute

```
rename pre_day_????????.txt* *.txt
```

You can also use the free [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php) which provides a neat GUI for renaming.